# Formatting similar to Rebelly API using Redoc

Tags: redoc

As per [redoc](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc) github page, there is an example of real life usage for [Rebilly API](https://api-reference.rebilly.com). I really like its formatting and would like to use as my formatting as well. I have created open api yaml file using redoc but formatting that comes out of box is not that appealing.

Does anyone know how can we get same formatting as [Rebilly API](https://api-reference.rebilly.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Rebilly is using a paid version of Redoc. You can test it for free at https://redoc.ly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any way we can customize the look and feel for the redoc? By any chance, do you have some documentation or example for that? 

I am more interested towards -

1. highlighting left sidebar panel item if we click on it 
2. Changing the color of right panel to light shade

Answer (score 0):

for the coloring, I think some basic theming/coloring is still possible in the free version of ReDoc. Try this online theme editor to see what are the available options: https://pointnet.github.io/redoc-editor/#/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30144268)